# Вывести результаты поиска Woocomerce на отдельный шаблон

Tags: woocommerce

Подскажите есть ли возможность вывести результат поиска на другой шаблон. На данный момент поиск выводит все на шаблон archive-product.php. Но нужно чтобы он использовал search.php. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скопируйте файл archive-product.php и вставьте его в папку woocommerce внутри вашей темы (если у вас нет этой папки, создайте ее)

Откройте файл и разделите содержимое внутри этого файла с помощью оператора php if

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    //разместите здесь контент результатов поиска (Вы можете скопировать код из файла archive-product.php, а также из content-product.php, чтобы создать необходимый результат)
} else {
    // здесь находится кастомный код(archive-product.php) 
}
```

Просто убедитесь, что эта строка кода всегда находится в верхней части файла:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
```

Comment: Спасибо, тебе добрый человек)))!!!!! Целый день эта проблема мне мозг выносила, а оказывается все так просто))))Рад безумно.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста и удачи в работе)!!